# Cut elimination proofs of the consistency of arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory

It is well known that one can use cut elimination to establish the consistency of arithmetic (though this involves assuming transfinite induction up to $\varepsilon_0$.) Most proofs, however, work within an infinitary system with an omega rule. I am looking for proofs of cut elimination in arithmetic that avoid this, and that just work using only the ordinary rules of first-order logic, without the omega-rule. I realize that induction etc. may have to be formulated as rules, rather than axioms, for this to be possible. Are there straightforward proofs of this sort?

I posted this question on mathstackexchange:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269309/cut-elimination-proofs-of-the-consistency-of-arithmetic .
I received a reference to Takeuti there, which I am currently looking at. It would be great if there were other options too.

Comment: A "provocateur" might cross-post after only one day... I say: wait a week before concluding there will be no answers.